# Feature collection to binary image results in single value image in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, image, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, feature-collection

I am trying to convert a feature collection to a binary image as described in [Creating binary image from FeatureCollection in Google Earth Engine](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/304923).

However, the result is an image with only one value and not a binary image as expected.

Here is my [code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/4dd25f2dd74f82bb717ad0c706bee1cc)

```js
//Load PAs Feature Collection filtered to Country
var PAs=ee.FeatureCollection("WCMC/WDPA/current/polygons").filter(ee.Filter.eq('ISO3', 'HND'));

// define ROI
var limites =ee.FeatureCollection("FAO/GAUL/2015/level0");
var roi= limites.filter(ee.Filter.eq('ADM0_NAME', 'Honduras'));

// background image
var HND0 = ee.Image.constant(1).clip(roi)
// replacement values
var PAs1 = ee.Image.constant(0).clip(PAs).clip(roi)
// foreground
var PAs_bin= HND0.where({test:PAs1, value:PAs1});


var distPAsVisPar = {min:0,
                     max:1,
                     "palette":['black','gray']};



Map.addLayer(HND0, {palette:['black']}, 'Background');
Map.addLayer(PAs1, {palette:['green']}, 'Foreground');
Map.addLayer(PAs_bin.clip(roi), distPAsVisPar, 'distance PAs fixed');

Map.centerObject(PAs)
```

Any suggestions to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You wrote `HND0.where({test:PAs1, value:PAs1})`.

`where` replaces pixels in an image wherever the `test` image's value is *nonzero*. But `PAs1` is *always zero* (or masked). To get a useful result, you can use the *mask* of `PAs1` instead:

```
var PAs_bin = HND0.where({test: PAs1.mask(), value: PAs1});
```

However, a better way to do this might be to *mosaic* the images. The mosaic operator takes the last unmasked pixel across a collection, so you can use it to overlay images:

```js
var PAs_bin = ee.ImageCollection([
  ee.Image.constant(1).toInt().clipToCollection(roi),
  ee.Image.constant(0).toInt().clipToCollection(PAs).clipToCollection(roi),
]).mosaic();
```

Note that I had to add `.int()` to convert the constant images to all have the same band type. Also, it's more efficient to use `.clipToCollection()` whenever the shape you're clipping to is a `FeatureCollection`.

A further refinement would be to avoid running `clipToCollection(roi)` twice:

```js
var PAs_bin = ee.ImageCollection([
  ee.Image.constant(1).toInt(),
  ee.Image.constant(0).toInt().clipToCollection(PAs),
])
  .mosaic()
  .clipToCollection(roi);
```

There is no need in Earth Engine to clip all of the *input* images to an operation. It doesn't save processing time; in fact, it would usually be slower than clipping the output, because pixel processing always starts with the requested *output* pixels and works backwards to find the needed inputs.